# How to check space available in Load Test Results Store?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, load-testing, web-testing

I am running web performance and load tests from Visual Studio Enterprise 2015, using 'on premises' test controller and agents. The Load Test Results Store is on the test controller machine. I often get an error message to the effect "cannot retrieve load test results. ... repository is out of space". I understand how to free up space by going to "Open and Manage Results", and removing results. Is there a way to check the 'used' or 'available' space in the Load Test Results Store database? Is there a way to check the size of a load test result, listed in the 'Open and Manage Results' window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I have found to find the used space via an SQL management console. Use the context (right click) menu on the database (LoadTest2010 by default for load tests) and select "Reports" => "Standard reports" => "Disk usage".

You also have to consider the database itself. Some versions of SQL Express have a maximum database size. Google has just shown me:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Express edition has a database size limit to 4GB.
>
> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Express edition has a database size limit to 4GB.
>
> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Express edition has a database size limit to 10GB.
>
> Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Express edition has a database size limit to 10GB.